# Using Grails 2.4.3 in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I've been unable to create/import a Grails 2.4.3 project with IntelliJ 13.1.4. For example, when I create a new module, choose Grails, then click the create button (highlighted below) and choose the location where Grails 2.4.3 is installed, the project is not created correctly (I get a module with just a `/src` directory instead of a Grails project) and Grails 2.4.3 is not added to the list of Global Libraries. I don't have this problem with any earlier version of Grails.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have used Grails 2.4.2 with Intellij 13.1.4 successfully.  What I did is create the application with the grails create-app command and then do a File / Import Project in Intellij.  Give that a try.

Comment: The problem only occurs for me with Grails 2.4.3

Comment: @Dónal But did you try the way Joe suggested? Create the app on the command line and the import it in IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution to the IntelliJ 13.1.4 and Grails 2.4.3 bug you can:

```
grails create app <app-name>
cd app-name
grails integrate-with --intellij
```

This configured the project correctly for me with just minor tweaks to SDK and application server. This is a minor twist on the work around described above.

See grails doc [here](https://grails.org/IDEA+Integration)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IntelliJ 13.1.4 and Grails 2.4.3, which i just downloaded.

After using the grails create-app command from the command line i had to import the project, by "create from existing sources" (point to the new top level folder), "Configure SDK" (to set for the Grails 2.4.3) and finally edit the run configuration. In a second test run with a new test project i did not have too configure the run config.

Then the Grails libs for the were downloaded and the basic app ran. Also the Grails specific option in the Intellij "Tools2 section were suddenly available.

So the given answer by Joe is the way to setup a new Grails project but the IDE should be fixed anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It is not consistent.  After several tries I can get some applications to work but it does not seem to be automatic.  I think I am going to go back to Grails 2.4.2 until this is resolved within Intellij 13.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot above, there are options for groovy/grails/griffon, and so far the alternative offered was command-line. Try choosing groovy option within intelliJ. 
We are using IDEA 13.1.4 with grails 1.3.7 and grails 2.2.1(diff projects) and saw the same issue. It appears this is an intelliJ issue and not so much the grails version, so reverting your grails won't gain you anything. Choosing groovy, you should see a prompt for grails directory structure. This does work if you are presented with this option. Seeing inconsistencies here. Thanks to all for posting your workarounds; never hurts to have multiple approaches.

-Duane